# Rotations in $SO(3)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, commutator, rotation

In quantum mechanics, would the position operator $\mathbf{x}$ commute with the operator for a rotation in $SO(3)$ of the form:

$$ \frac{i}{h} \mathbf{\omega} \cdot \mathbf{L} ?$$

Where $\omega$ is the angle rotated about the axis and $\mathbf{L}$ is the angular momentum.

Comment: If it did, *how* would the latter rotate it?

Comment: Are you saying $\omega$ is a scalar here ?

Comment: no just represtent anglular momentum op in position speace by using spherical coordinates. than use a test function to see if it commutes.